# Regex that grabs all occurrences of strings that start with '@'

Tags: regex, string

I am new to writing Regular Expressions and I'm building an app that needs to look for all occurrences of the `@` symbol and the rest of the string. For example:

```
.btn-primary{
 color: @color;
 background-color: @background-color;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 font-weight: bold;
 &:hover{
  background-color: darken(@background-color, 15%);
 }
}
```

I would like a regex that would search this LESS code and return to me all FULL strings that start with `@`. I tried doing this with an online regex builder and came up with `/\A@\S*/` but I'm almost sure that is not correct.

Thank You For Your Help!

Comment: What is your desired output for the above example?

Comment: Presumably you're splitting on newline (or carriage returns) and expecting something like `background-color: @background-color;` to be the complete match on that line (since it has an `@` symbol) ?

Comment: The desired output is all occurrences of all strings that start with `@` and grab the rest of the string minus a `;` or `,`. So `background-color: @background-color;` would return me just `@background-color`. I guess I'm looking for a PhP function that would take a code block as a parameter and return to me all strings mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
(@[a-zA-Z-]+)
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yY2xX0/1)